# Jsessionid interferes with crawling

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, jsessionid

I am practicing crawling with python3.

I am crawling this site.

```
http://www.keri.org/web/www/research_0201?p_p_id=EXT_BBS&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_EXT_BBS_struts_action=%2Fext%2Fbbs%2Fview&_EXT_BBS_sCategory=&_EXT_BBS_sKeyType=&_EXT_BBS_sKeyword=&_EXT_BBS_curPage=1&_EXT_BBS_optKeyType1=&_EXT_BBS_optKeyType2=&_EXT_BBS_optKeyword1=&_EXT_BBS_optKeyword2=&_EXT_BBS_sLayoutId=0
```

I want to get the address of pdf from html code.

ex) In html, pdf down url is

```
http://www.keri.org/web/www/research_0201?p_p_id=EXT_BBS&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_EXT_BBS_struts_action=%2Fext%2Fbbs%2Fget_file&_EXT_BBS_extFileId=5326
```

But, My crawler results

```
http://www.keri.org/web/www/research_0201**;jsessionid=3875698676A3025D8877C4EEBA67D6DF**p_p_id=EXT_BBS&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_EXT_BBS_struts_action=%2Fext%2Fbbs%2Fget_file&_EXT_BBS_extFileId=5306
```

I can not even download the file to the address below.

Where did jsessionid come from?

I can just erase it, but I wonder why.

**
Why is the URL so long? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested in my code that `jsessionid` dose not affect the download file:

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('http://www.keri.org/web/www/research_0201?p_p_id=EXT_BBS&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_EXT_BBS_struts_action=%2Fext%2Fbbs%2Fview&_EXT_BBS_sCategory=&_EXT_BBS_sKeyType=&_EXT_BBS_sKeyword=&_EXT_BBS_curPage=1&_EXT_BBS_optKeyType1=&_EXT_BBS_optKeyType2=&_EXT_BBS_optKeyword1=&_EXT_BBS_optKeyword2=&_EXT_BBS_sLayoutId=0')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
down_links = [(a.get('href'), a.find_previous('a').text )for a in soup('a', class_="download")]
for link, title in down_links:
    filename = title + '.pdf'
    r = requests.get(link, stream=True, headers=headers)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: @ Really? I typed the download url In my web browser directly . However, I could not download the file....Anyway, thank you~!!!